# Expect: using a variable as expect string

Tags: tcl, expect

Let me say I have something like....

```
set timeout 10
expect {
    "login:"    {
        send "$USER\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "assword:"  {
        send "$PASSWORD\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    $PROMPT {
        send_user "Successfully logged in."
    }
}
```

I have a problem with defining the $PROMPT

All these give an error...

```
set PROMPT   {-re ">|:"}
set PROMPT   "-re \">|:\""
set PROMPT   {-regexp ">|:"}
```

I get error like...

```
bad flag "-regexp ":|>"": must be -glob, -regexp, -exact, -notransfer, -nocase, -i, -indices, -iread, -timestamp, -timeout, -nobrace, or --
```

*What is the correct way of assigning the variable and (more importantly) what is the concept that I have violated for this error to happen?*

Thanking You in advance!

Comment: The $PROMPT variable represents one word.  The arguments for `-regexp` can not be contained in the variable.  Try replacing `$PROMPT {...` with `-regexp ":|>" {...` within the expect statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should write like this:

```
set PROMPT {>|:}
expect {
  -re $PROMPT { ... }
  ...
}
```

And to be safer you better define a more precise `PROMPT` as some commands may also output chars like `>` or `:`.

Comment: Correct: the option has to be outside the variable. There are ways to work around it, but they're a bit complicated. Much easier to just say that you're always going to specify the prompt as a RE.